# Show output not in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I created a slider, which fulfills my needs.
But I do not want to show the output value in an input.

Here is my Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOZGVx?editors=1010

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
function update() {            
     $optiona = $("#optiona").val();
     $optionb = $("#optionb").val();
     $totalsum = ($optiona * 0.75 * $optionb * 9) - ($optiona * $optionb);
     $("#totalsum").val($totalsum);
}
 
debugger;
 
$("#slider-optiona").slider({
    max:30,
    min:1,
    step:1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {  
    $(this).parent().find("#optiona").val(ui.value);
    $("#optiona").val(ui.value);
                update();
    },
    create: function(event, ui){
        $(this).slider('value',$(this).parent().find("#optiona").val());
    }
});
 
  
$("#slider-optionb").slider({
    max:100,
    min:1,
    step:1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {  
     $(this).parent().find("#optionb").val(ui.value);

     $("#optionb").val(ui.value);
                update();
       
    },
    create: function(event, ui){
        $(this).slider('value',$(this).parent().find("#optionb").val());
    }
});

update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Option A<div id="slider-optiona"></div>
Choice: <input type="text" id="optiona" value="12" disabled /><br /><br />
 
Option B<div id="slider-optionb"></div>
Choice: <input type="text" id="optionb" value="30" disabled/><br /><br /><br />

Sum
<input id="totalsum" type="text" disabled/><br />
```

**What I want:**
I want the output to be not displayed in a input, but in a span or something like this.

I already tried it with

```
<span type="text" id="optionb"></span>
```

But it didn't worked :(

And the further question to the real experts: how can I show the totalsum in a complete currency value, e.g 145.50 instead of 145.5 at the moment.

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: `<span>` tags don't need a `type` attribute and to place the output in a `span` you can use `.text()` or `.html()` rather than `.val()` since `span` tags don't have a value. **Also** don't use the same `ID` more than one. `ID`'s are supposed to be unique, use a `class` for multiple/groups of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *MenuItem42* stated, you just need to use jQuery's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function instead of [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) when you are working with div, span, etc. Also, do not specify `type` attribute for `span` because it does not support it.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
function update() {            
     $optiona = $("#optiona").text();
     $optionb = $("#optionb").text();
     $totalsum = ($optiona * 0.75 * $optionb * 9) - ($optiona * $optionb);
     $("#totalsum").text($totalsum);
}
 
debugger;
 
$("#slider-optiona").slider({
    max:30,
    min:1,
    step:1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {  
    $(this).parent().find("#optiona").text(ui.value);
    $("#optiona").val(ui.value);
                update();
    },
    create: function(event, ui){
        $(this).slider('value',$(this).parent().find("#optiona").text());
    }
});
 
  
$("#slider-optionb").slider({
    max:100,
    min:1,
    step:1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {  
     $(this).parent().find("#optionb").text(ui.value);

     $("#optionb").val(ui.value);
                update();
       
    },
    create: function(event, ui){
        $(this).slider('value',$(this).parent().find("#optionb").text());
    }
});

update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Option A<div id="slider-optiona"></div>
Choice: <span id="optiona">12</span><br /><br />
 
Option B<div id="slider-optionb"></div>
Choice: <span id="optionb">30</span><br /><br />

Sum
<span id="totalsum"></span>
```

Comment: ah awesome and could you help me to "expand" the totalsum to a X.XXX,XX type? So, when the result is just 320, it should show 320,00. Or is this a crazy thing?

Answer (score 0):

When you want write in span you have to use .text() instead of .val()